# How to obtain the memory usage in percentage

Tags: time-series, metrics, influxdb

I am using the [collected memory plugin](https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:Memory) to get metrics from a web server every minute `Interval 60` and storing them remotely into an [influxdb](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.5/) server `version 1.5.1`.

This is are the series I have:

```
> SHOW SERIES FROM memory_value WHERE host = 'webserver'

key
---
memory_value,host=webserver,type=memory,type_instance=buffered
memory_value,host=webserver,type=memory,type_instance=cached
memory_value,host=webserver,type=memory,type_instance=free
memory_value,host=webserver,type=memory,type_instance=slab_recl
memory_value,host=webserver,type=memory,type_instance=slab_unrecl
memory_value,host=webserver,type=memory,type_instance=used
```

And this are some values:

```
> SELECT * FROM memory_value WHERE host='webserver' AND time > now() -1m
name: memory_value
time                host      type   type_instance value
----                ----      ----   ------------- -----
1525704284702691476 webserver memory buffered      2138112
1525704284702691476 webserver memory cached        462839808
1525704284702691476 webserver memory free          1184563200
1525704284702691476 webserver memory slab_recl     45092864
1525704284702691476 webserver memory slab_unrecl   34017280
1525704284702691476 webserver memory used          199811072
```

To obtain the total memory I need to sum `free` + `used`, then to obtain the obtain the percentage I need to do:

```
used * 100 / (free + used)
```

I can get the `free` value using:

```
> SELECT mean(value) FROM memory_value WHERE host='webserver' and "type_instance" = 'free' AND time > now() -1m
    name: memory_value
time                mean
----                ----
1525704816631763155 321410389.3333333
```

Same with the `used`:

```
> SELECT mean(value) FROM memory_value WHERE host='webserver' and "type_instance" = 'used' AND time > now() -1m
name: memory_value
time                mean
----                ----
1525704846204790445 199811072
```

But wondering how could I obtain the values within the same query so that I could `sum` them and get the `total available memory`  and then calculate the used percentage.

I found that I could sum the series by using:

```
> SELECT SUM(value) FROM memory_value WHERE host='webserver' AND type_instance =~ /(free|used)/ AND time > NOW() -1m
name: memory_value
time                sum
----                ---
1525708703989094507 1384349696
```

But still, need to now find how to put all together in order to calculate the percentage.

Comment: If `(free+used)` is constant in time just hardcode it in query for `used`: `SELECT mean(free) * 100 / TOTALMEMVALUE FROM ....`

Comment: @YuriLachin what would be the value of `TOTALMEMVALUE` how to make the full query?

Comment: Total RAM memory on server is what `cat /proc/meminfo` or `free -m` commands show. `SELECT mean(value) / 1234567890  FROM memory_value WHERE host='webserver' and "type_instance" = 'used' AND time > now() -1m`

Comment: @YuriLachin I would like to do it from the DB since is more os agnostic, in FreeBSD, for example, there is no `/proc/meminfo`

Comment: Then it is really tricky to do with influxdb as it doesn't support math across measurements and series. In your case problem is that `used` and `free` are `tag values` rather than  `fields` in one measurement. I would suggest replace collectd with equivalent telegraf plugin (`[[inputs.mem]]`) for memory related metrics where they are all in one record as fields. Then the query might look like: `select mean("memutil") from (select 100*used/(used+free) as "memutil" from mem where time > now() - 1h) where time > now() - 1h group by time(1m)`